# Expression for elastic collision of 2 balls

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, energy-conservation, collision

Say 2 non-identical balls with mass m1 and m2 collide in 2d. How would I find an expression for their velocity vectors after the collision?

By conservation of KE, I have: (where U and V are 2d vectors)
0.5*m1*U1^2 + 0.5*m2*U2^2 = 0.5*m1*V1^2 + 0.5*m2*V2^2

By conservation of momentum I have:
m1U1 + m2U2 = m1V1 + m2V2

I'm assuming I'd have to manipulate these equations to find an expression for V1 and V2, however I am finding it hard to rearrange them to do this.

Is this correct? Would I have to consider relative velocities instead?

Answer (score 1):

Your 2 equations are not enough. You have 1 scalar equation (energy) and 1 vector equation in 2D (momentum), so in total you have 3 scalar equations.

But you have 4 unknown values (V1 and V2 being 2D vectors), so from 3 equations you can't find the 4 values needed.

What you need in addition, is the geometry of the impact. The two balls touch in one point. Ignoring friction, they will only exchange a momentum component perpendicular to the impact surface (along the line connecting the ball centers).

This matches everyday experience. Billards players control the directions of the balls after impact mainly by varying the impact point (aiming to the center of the other ball or more left or right). This shows that just knowing the velocities isn't enough.